# Copying values from a table row to a modal

Tags: php, html, html-table, modal-dialog

I have wrote an HTML table presenting users' information from an SQL database.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Role</th>>
        <th>Attribute</th>
        </th>
        <th>Ideas/Score</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($result=m ysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) { $usertoattrquery="SELECT * FROM usertoattr WHERE usertoattr.user_id=" .$result[user_id]; $attrfetch=mysqli_query($con,$usertoattrquery) or die ( 'could no connect with instructions'); echo "<tr><td>".$result[ "username"]. "</td><td>" .$result[ "password"]. "</td>
    <td>" .$result[ "role"]. "</td><td>only for Eval</td><td>coming soon</td><td>
         <a href='#editUser' role='button'  class='btn' data-toggle='modal'>Edit</a> </td>
         <td><button class='btn'onclick='deleteConfirm()'>Delete</button> </td></tr>"; } ?>
</table>
```

I would like when someone pushes the button "Edit" in a specific row a Modal to be opened and the values from this table row to be copied (for example name and password) inside the modal.

```
<div id="editUser" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
     <h3 id="myModalLabel">Edit User</h3>
User Name
    <input type="text">
    <br>User Password
    <input type="text">
    <br>User Role
    <select>
        <option>Evaluator</option>
        <option>Observer</option>
    </select>
    <br>User Attribute
    <select multiple>
        <option>Economics</option>
        <option>Software</option>
        <option>Management</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>OK</button>
    <button class='btn' data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

How is that possible?

Comment: I think you should be looking at javascript to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly add an id to each of your `<td>` (just make sure each one is different multiple id's are bad!!)

Then have your javascript use that value (.innerHTML) to set the value of your input text inside your modal.